# Access Twitter API using HTTP requests in PHP

Tags: php, http, twitter, twitter-oauth

I want to update my twitter status using the Twitter API. Here is my code:

```
$access_token = "{Twitter Access Token}";
$access_secret = "{Twitter Access Token Secret}";
$send_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";

$opts = array('http' => array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded&oauth_token=$access_token&oauth_token_secret=$access_secret",
    'content' => 'status=Hello'
) );

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents($send_url, false, $context);
echo $result;
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I sending through the oAuth tokens correctly?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: I want it to update the status of the user but that doesn't happen.